# Python to Swift Conversion

Tags: swift

I am just starting in Swift. I was wondering if there is a way to convert a Python code to Swift 5? My Python code is rather short and simple. The end result in the Python code below is to print out randomly selected items from a list; matched with the days of the week. I managed to figure out the randomization in Swift but not how to assign those 7 randomly selected items to the respective days of the week.
MY Python Code:

```
def randomMenu():
    meals = ["Chicken", "Hamburgers", "Hot Dogs", "Lamb", "Pizza", "Pork Chops", "Schnitzel", "Shrimp", "Spaghetti", "BBQ", "Tacos", "Takeout", "Takeout Pizza", "Mexican", "Schaschlik", "Korean", "Harissa"]

    days = ['Mon', 'Tue' , 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun']

    random.shuffle(meals)

     day_meals = random.sample(meals , 7)

     for index in range(7):
        print(f'The selected meal for {days[index]}:   {day_meals[index]}')

randomMenu()
```

Here is what I'd tried so far with swift.

```
let menuItems = ["Salmon", "Salad", "Curry", "Sushi", "Pizza", "Chicken", "Hamburgers", "Hot Dogs", "Lamb", "Pork Chops", "Schnitzel", "Shrimp", "Spaghetti", "BBQ", "Tacos", "Takeout", "Mexican", "Schaschlik", "Korean", "Harissa"]
var resultSet = Set<String>()
while resultSet.count < 7 {
    let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(menuItems.count)))
    resultSet.insert(menuItems[randomIndex])
}
let resultArray = Array(resultSet)
print(resultArray)
```

Comment: So, you had already created an array with seven randomised menu items. Now, what exactly you want to do. What do you mean by assign those 7 randomly selected items to the respective days of the week? Do you wanna make a dictionary where key would be day and value would be menu item?

Comment: Sorry, I tried posting the Swift code but it becomes difficult to read when it's posted - can't seem to format properly. The 7 randomly selected items (day_meals) get assigned (one) to each days of the week (days). The end results looks something like this: Mon: Hot Dogs  Tue: Chicken Wed: Lamb Thur: Pizza etc. for each day of the week.

Comment: If you just want to print that out to the console, you can refer answer posted by iOSDev. Or else, clarify a bit more about what you want to do.

Comment: The end result is to create an iOS app (for personal use) incorporating this (code) functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let days = ["Mon", "Tue" , "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
let menuItems = ["Salmon", "Salad", "Curry", "Sushi", "Pizza", "Chicken", "Hamburgers", "Hot Dogs", "Lamb", "Pork Chops", "Schnitzel", "Shrimp", "Spaghetti", "BBQ", "Tacos", "Takeout", "Mexican", "Schaschlik", "Korean", "Harissa"]
var resultSet = Set<String>()
while resultSet.count < 7, let random = menuItems.randomElement() {
    resultSet.insert(random)
}
let resultArray = Array(resultSet)

for (day, item) in zip(days, resultArray) {
    print("The selected meal for \(day):   \(item)")
}
```

Without Set

```
let resultArray = Array(menuItems.shuffled().prefix(upTo: 7))
for (day, item) in zip(days, resultArray) {
    print("The selected meal for \(day):   \(item)")
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out and please don't spend too much time on. Your help is very much appreciated. When I run the code (with Set) I get the following error message on line 5 after 'resultSet...' the error indicates "Value of optional type 'String?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'String'. Something which I can research and try to fix. Again thank you for your time and assistance, very much appreciated. The code Without Set works fine and just what I wanted.

Comment: @RobertSalter `menuItems.randomElement()` returns an optional string. Check the updated answer

Comment: Again, thank you for taking the time to help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `shuffled()` on your meals array

```
let menuItems = ["Salmon", "Salad", "Curry", "Sushi", "Pizza", "Chicken", "Hamburgers", "Hot Dogs", "Lamb", "Pork Chops", "Schnitzel", "Shrimp", "Spaghetti", "BBQ", "Tacos", "Takeout", "Mexican", "Schaschlik", "Korean", "Harissa"]
let days = ["Mon", "Tue" , "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]

let random = menuItems.shuffled()
for (index, value) in days.enumerated() {
    print("\(value) \(random[index])")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I understand this code correctly, this code doesn't really generate a random selection. Instead, it just "shuffles" the menuItems and the "enumerated" iterates over the items and returns a sequence of pairs - the value represents the 'days' and the index represents the 'meuItems' . A lot to learn.....thank you again for your response.

Comment: @RobertSalter, well the shuffle of the array puts them in random order so it is not really necessary to create a new collection (set, array etc) from just the first 7. I guess what you want to do with that array in the end determines what the best way to pair it with the weekday array.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to explain.